# control instantiation of osgi declarative service

Tags: java, osgi, factory, declarative-services

I am looking for a simple way to control the instantiation of a declarative service.

What I want is something like a factory which is asked to return an instance of a component, but where I can control the instantiation.

Currently I just found the ComponentFactory where I just can call newInstance with a given dictionary. But what I really want, is something like this, assuming IComponent is the declarative service interface and MyComponent is the implementation class

```
public class MyComponentFactory implements ? {

   public IComponent newInstance() {
       return new MyComponent("firstParameter", "secondParameter");
   }
}
```

Is there something possible like this with declarative services, or do I need to use my own service registration in a bundle activation code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Who controls the instantiation? I.e., who will call `newInstance`? The service consumer? Or you want the framework to do it automatically; if so, then at what times/events?

Comment: The framework should do it automatically, when a service instance is needed. i.e. a service consumer requests the OSGI service registry for the service "IComponent".

Comment: But that's what DS already does. It creates the component on the first demand from a service consumer.

Comment: I know, thats my problem. The framework forces a 0 argument constructor. I thought there is maybe a way around, so that the framework says: "I need a new component, i delegate the instanciation to your special class"

Comment: What's wrong with the client + dictionary? Alternatively, if those parameters are statically coded why not move these to a zero arg constructor that invokes the parameterized constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DS does not provide for the level of instance creation indirection you are looking for. DS will always use the public no-args constructor and then call the specified activator method to complete the instance initialization.

Comment: so looks like the is no way for a n-arg constructor of the component

Comment: That is correct. DS does not support constructor injection. It supports activate, modified and deactivate methods to inject configuration and bind and unbind methods to inject dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative for such service instantiation control is using a combination of DS and CM.

You must set configuration-policy="require" in the DS xml and use CM to create a configuration instance that will be used to pass a Dictionary containing all properties that you need (only types supported by DS of course) to the created service instance. You can even use a propertie file plus Felix File Install for that connfiguration.

If that is not enough you have another alternative that is to track for new created service and call a setup(args) method just after you have added a configuration using CM.